# Error when attempting to place string into nested struct

Tags: c, struct

I have a nested struct, which I am attempting to fill with user data. The struct:

```
typedef struct gameInfo 
{
    char title[MAX];
    char platform[MAX];
    char developer[MAX];
    unsigned int year;

    struct borrowerInfo
        {
            bool borrowed;
            char nameOfBorrower[MAX];
            char date[MAX];
        } borrower;
} game;
```

I am using `gets()` and `scanf()` to get the data from the user:

```
gets(game.title);
gets(game.platform);
gets(game.developer);
scanf("%d",&game.year);
```

However, I get the error:

```
error: expected expression before 'game'
   gets(game.title);
        ^~~~
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`game` is the name of a type, not a variable.  You need to declare a variable of that type:

```
game mygame;
```

Then populate `mygame`.

Also, never user `gets`, as the function can overrun the buffer it's writing to.  Better to use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Or remove the `typedef` keyword.